# List dependencies for module, not package

Tags: go, module, package, dependencies

If I have this file:

```
package main
import "github.com/dinedal/textql/storage"
```

I can list the dependencies using one of these:

```
go list -deps
go mod graph
```

However if I have this file instead:

```
package main
import "github.com/dinedal/textql"
```

All the dependencies are not listed. For example looking at the [mod file](//github.com/dinedal/textql/blob/master/go.mod),
none of the packages under `require` are listed now. Finally I tried this with an
interesting result:

```
PS C:\> go list -deps github.com/dinedal/textql
go: finding module for package github.com/dinedal/textql
module github.com/dinedal/textql@latest found
(v0.0.0-20200608170856-250cf763f52c), but does not contain package
github.com/dinedal/textql
```

Comment: Exactly as the error indicates: That module does not contain a package called `github.com/dinedal/textql`.  If you [look at it](https://github.com/dinedal/textql), it's apparent why: There are no `.go` files in the top-level directory.

Comment: @StevenPenny: Try `go list -deps github.com/dinedal/textql/...` That's not "for a module", exactly.  It's "For a path, and its children". But in most common cases, they're effectively the same.

Comment: Those packages must be installed first.  i.e. `go get github.com/dinedal/textql/whatever`.  `go list` doesn't automatically download anything.

Comment: I don't mind posting an answer, but first there needs to be a question that the information answers :) Do you want to clarify your question? It's a bit of an XY Problem right now.

Comment: Your answer looks good. No need to add my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments, I was able to get a list of dependencies for a module
like this:

```
go mod init deps
go get github.com/dinedal/textql
go list -deps github.com/dinedal/textql/...
```

Also this command can be used for testing, as it clears out of the module cache:

```
go clean -modcache
```